# I am having trouble connecting my remote postgres service to pg_admin.Tried all possible way still failing

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to connect my remote postgres service which is on a VM to my desktop pg_admin, but I am getting the same error again and again. I saw many people have the same issue and the solutions provided on stackoverflow is not helping me.
As of now these are the configurations I have made in postgres conf file and pg_hba.conf file.

**pg_hba.conf :**

```
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.
host    replication     replication     master_ip/24      md5
host       all            all             0.0.0.0/0       md5


# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host       all            all           my_ip/32       md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all              my_ip/32               md5
host    all             all              ::/0                   md5
host       all          all               0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

**postgresql.conf :**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)
```

pg_admin connection window :

[image: data that I add in pg_admin]

Error that I get while connecting :

[image]

let me know what can be the possible issue for this, I have tried adding entry on pg_hba.conf and listen_port is allowd "*".
If any other info is needed please comment. There are many similar questions but that didn't help that's why adding the question.

Comment: Did you restart the server after the changes? Are you sure you made the changes to the conf files for the correct server? You blurred out the host, but is it covered by the net masks in `pg_hba.conf`? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have added the right IP in pg_hba.conf with 32 as net mask (host    all             all              my_ip/32               md5). I don't know much about net mask but that's what I am using, please check the pg_hba.conf file that I have shared in the question.

Comment: You have not answered the other questions in my comment.  Is `my_ip` the IP for the host you are connecting from? In other words for the client you are trying to connect as?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, my_ip is the IP(my computers IP) to which I want to connect this remote service.